# How to make a sidebar nav collapse to a drop-down nav small widths in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

In Bootstrap, is there a way to make a sidebar nav (class="nav-list") collapse to a drop-down nav at low widths? To illustrate:

Move from this:

[image]

To this at a given width breakpoint:

[image]

I want the sidebar to be the main nav at desktop widths, but don't want the full thing displayed on mobile.

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap latest responsive it does it by default. Make sure you're following the guides or starting with a demo.

Comment: Resize this page to see it: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Comment: What you are looking for is called Off-Canvas,
check this example based on boostrap 3 http://bootply.com/78559#

And this one released by the twitterbootstrap guys http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/